# Can't fetch recently viewed list view information for custom objects

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, soql, list-view, recentlyviewed

I am trying to fetch existing list views for a **custom object**, I can find 'Recently viewed' list filter in custom object home page or in its standard tab. But when I query it by SOQL `SELECT id, Name, DeveloperName FROM ListView WHERE sObjectType = : objectApiName ORDER By Name ASC` it finds 'All' list which was created by default and other custom lists excluding recently viewed. For a standard object, this SOQL finds all the list view filters including recently viewed. What am I missing here?